# How to implement virtual keyboard for secure Login form?

Tags: security, keyboard, frontend

My boss gave my a blank check in order to develop a login form extremly secure. I've been researching about how to do this using a username, password and captcha. This question is refered to the password input. I believe the best way to do it is implementing a virtual keyboard

**Virtual keyboard**
The REST sends to the frontend an array with 10 numbers, every number in this array indicates a position for the key that will be render in the view. The user will type his password using this generated keyboard and press `Login`. The post request will send the **positions** of the keys pressed in the virtual keyboard to the Backend. The backend will match the positions to the real pin use number's.

My questions:

1. Is this the correct way to implement this component, am I missing something?
2. Does anyone have experience doing this kind of things to share some knowledge about good practices, links, or any know-how?

Maybe is not an exact question, but I think this can contribute to the knowledge about this component that is very used in banking applications.

NOTE: Obviusly all requests and response will work with tokens for security.

Comment: You may want to check out M-Pin by CertiVox. This is an LOA 3 solution that gets rid of your need to store credentials, provides 2FA using a PIN in JavaScript so no plugins required and is in use by Experian, NTT and others. It's also open source and there is a community addition.

Comment: Note: in full disclosure I am the chief bottle washer at CertiVox.

Answer (score 2):

This would defeat the simplest general-purpose keylogger trojans, but it would fail to prevent:

a. more sophisticated modern trojans that, eg, take mini-screenshots of what's under the mouse on each click on a login page, specifically to default virtual keyboards;

b. anything that cares enough about your site to specifically target it and work around your code.

Ultimately you cannot win against the client-side trojan (man-in-the-browser) attack. The attacker's code is working from a higher level of privilege than you are so anything you can do to defend, the attacker can work around.

At best you can make it more annoying to work around than it is worth for the attacker. This can easily become an arms race. But any such measures you take will hurt the usability and accessibility of your site. For most sites the limited protection a virtual keyboard offers is outweighed by the customer inconvenience.

Comment: I agree with you, and also, this would not work nicely with password managers. To prevent passwords being stolen by keyloggers, you'd probably be weakening the passwords used, which is a much larger risk.